# perform mb_substr using DoubleQuotes

Tags: php

I am trying to return the part of a string which is between double quotes, using mb_substr.  The string is in this format  `123"NEW"43`.   I would like to get only "NEW"

```
  $state1= mb_substr($_POST["list1"],\"\");
```

Comment: You realise that the second argument for mb_substr() isn't a string value? I think you're looking at the wrong function.

Comment: Improve wording to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is the better function here. Just use it like this:

(Here I just grab everything between double quotes from your string)

```
<?php

    $str = $_POST["list1"] = '123"NEW"43';
    preg_match_all("/\"(.*?)\"/u", $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => "NEW" ) [1] => Array ( [0] => NEW ) )
```

Now you can access it like this:

```
echo $matches[0][0];
```